# Only allow user to close a JavaScript alert after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, alert

Is it possible to prevent a user from closing a JavaScript alert until 10 seconds have passed?

I trigger an alert, and then user must wait "x" seconds to be able to close it.

Comment: If I ever found your application doing that to me, it would be the last time I ever used that application!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a better way:

You'll want to avoid alert, since you have no control over the dialog box with it. Instead, try a modal dialog like ThickBox. It's a jQuery plugin (so you'll need the jQuery library). Look at the "inline" example on this page: (click "demo" then "Show hidden modal content" link)

http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/#sectiond-1

Initially, hide the `OK` button and use a `setTimeout()` to then show it after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Not using `alert`, You have to create your own (almost) modal dialog using JS and HTML with an OK button that is disabled, then use `setTimeout` to enable it after ten seconds

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. If it were, it could be abused easily.